# Clear console output using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I am trying to create a time display (h:mm:ss) with just using the console and not on a web page. The time should be set initially and from there display the time as it changes.

When using the output console (in the web browser) or in vscode, is it possible for js or node.js to clear the console or the outputs in the console without using an extension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, with the aptly named [`console.clear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/clear) function.